# Insert values into a mysql database in java

Tags: java, mysql

Hi I am trying to insert data into my database but get thrown the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Validations.RegisterValidation.<init>(RegisterValidation.java:26)
    at ui.RegistrationUI$2.mouseClicked(RegistrationUI.java:49)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6530)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4542)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

my insert code is as follows:

```
public boolean addUser(String name, String surname, String email, String password) throws SQLException {
    String query = "INSERT INTO users(name, surname, email, password)"
            + "VALUES('" + name +"', '" + surname + "', '" + email + "', '" + password + "')";

    statement.executeUpdate(query);
    return true;
}
```

All the data being inserted is in string form and as far as I know my SQL is correct. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the relevant code where you pass the variables to your method and invoke it. Also the code for `Validations.RegisterValidation` seeing as that's where the error occurs.

Comment: This exception has nothing to do with your executing the SQL query. There's a problem with your GUI components that you need to fix.

Comment: The stack trace that you've posted indicates that you're trying to access a null field somewhere in your mouse click listener.

Comment: I have done tests for that and my GUI components are working perfectly. its when I call the insert that it gives me the error

Comment: @JulienVincent There is nothing wrong with your insert besides possible sql injection risk. The error occurs in your mouseClicked and RegisterValidation. There's a null value.

Comment: @JulienVincent if the `query` variable is not `null` which in this case isn't, the `executeUpdate()` method would ALWAYS throw an `SQLException` if it encounters any exception.

Comment: It shouldn't be encountering an exception though?